# how do I test controller method using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, methods, rspec, controller

I'm trying to learn rspec.  I can't seem to test a rails controller method.  When I call the method in the test, rspec just returns an undefined method error.  Here is my test example

```
it 'should return 99 if large' do
  GamesController.testme(1000).should == 99
end
```

and here is the error:

```
 Failure/Error: GamesController.testme(1000).should == 99
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `testme' for GamesController:Class
```

I do have a testme method in the GamesController.  I don't understand why the test code cannot see my methods.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the correct way is this:

```
describe GamesController do
  it 'should return 99 if large' do
    controller.testme(1000).should == 99
  end
end
```

In a rails controller spec, when you put the controller class in `describe`, you can use `controller` method to get an instance :P
Obviously, if `testme` method is private, you still have to use `controller.send :testme`

Comment: Thankyou very much - this is surprisingly hard to find in the docs

Answer (score 8):

You try to test class method, but controller has instance method

You need `GamesController.new.testme(1000).should == 99`

Or even `GamesController.new.send(:testme, 1000).should == 99`, because, as I think, this is not action method, but private or protected.

Action methods are tested [this way](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-9/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec)

Comment: OK.  Now I see that.  The difference between the class and instance methods is a subtlety that escaped me.  As you can tell, I am still new to ruby and rails.  By the way, the link to the rspec-rails documentation is good.  I was not aware of that resource.  Thank you.